# Why does Google Cloud Function run a global function multiple times after deploy?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have set multiple triggers, like:

```
exports.doSomething = functions.firestore.document('col/{doc}').onCreate(event => {})
```

Than I have a function that I want to run instant when I deployed. That looks something like this:

```
now()
function now(){
    console.log("running function")
}
```

And I get this in my logs:

[image]

Why does it run so many times and gets called by other functions?

Full code, just tested it and running function gets called 4 times, the same amount as triggers I have set:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore()
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');

exports.z = functions.firestore.document('converasdassdtIP/{UID}').onCreate(event => { })
exports.x = functions.firestore.document('sads/{UID}').onCreate(event => { })
exports.n = functions.firestore.document('asdasasdsa/{UID}').onCreate(event => { })
exports.m = functions.firestore.document('converasdasddtIP/{UID}').onCreate(event => { })

now()
function now(){
    console.log("running function")
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `now()`? Can you add your some of your `functions/index.js` to the question?

Comment: @Callam see my edit

Comment: Your call on `now()` is called everytime a function is triggered because it is in the root scope of your `index.js` file, and so every Cloud Function that runs, you will see this log. What do you want to achieve with this log? When do you want it to print?

Comment: @Callam O, I am very unfamiliar with javascript. Let's say I want to do a onetime-setup every time I deploy something to Firebase, what/how should I do that? I want the function now() to be ran only once.

Comment: When do you only what it to run when you're deploying? And what are you deploying, all the functions, or just a particular one?

Comment: @Callam I want to deploy every function that I have in my index.js/question, and the function now() should be ran once: when I deployed the functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Functions doesn't provide a way to run a bit of code at the time of deploy.  Your function is obviously being run multiple times, and you should expect it to be run *even more times* as new server instances are allocated (and destroyed) in tandem with the load on your project.  This is how Cloud Functions scales.  There is definitely not just one server instance handling all your requests.  You should expect any global code to be run repeatedly.

If you want to run some code exactly once after deploy, make an exported funciton (maybe HTTPS) and trigger it after you deploy.  Maybe you could write a script that both deploys your code then triggers the function with curl or some other mechanism you choose.